# Understanding what ddrescue is telling me

Tags: usb-drive, external-hdd, ddrescue

Essentially what I want to know is, has `ddrescue` made any progress? Is my hdd pretty well dead?

After executing

```
sudo ddrescue -d -r3 /dev/sdb dos_pace.img dos_pace-ddrescue.log
```

on a USB 2.0-enclosed drive, I've got

```
GNU ddrescue 1.19
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
rescued:         0 B,  errsize:   1376 MB,  current rate:        0 B/s
   ipos:     1083 MB,   errors:    4170,    average rate:        0 B/s
   opos:     1083 MB, run time:    4.10 h,  successful read:    4.10 h ago
Copying non-tried blocks... Pass 3 (forwards)
```

and the image file is 0 bytes. That looks kind of grim, but I don't know what to make of all those figures.